# Set up text boxes in MS Access form as array?

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

Is there a way to set up text boxes in Access forms as arrays for use in loops with VBA?

Comment: sort of yes. `Me.Controls(someString & i)`

Comment: If you have a recordsource you could possibly use a continuous form.

Comment: yes, that also works, it depends on the use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the controls and iterate through them. Have to pick an iterable naming scheme.

```
Me.Controls("txt" & intloop)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would disagree with serakfalcon in terms of requiring a certain naming schema to iterate through textboxes.  The proper way would be to look at the control type.  It should really be done like this:

```
Dim ctl As Access.Control

For Each ctl In Forms!MyForm.Controls
    If ctl.ControlType = acTextbox Then
         '...your code here.
    End If
Next
```

This does not require a specific naming schema (not saying it is a bad idea, it isn't) and you know for sure the object is what you are expecting.

Comment: I'd go further and use the `.Tag` property of the control as well as the type. This allows you to keep a relevant name for the control rather than adhering to some iterative naming scheme, then select a subset of controls to work with, in case there are controls of that type that are outwith the scope of the process.